# Statistics about Android devices with MIPS processors

Tags: android, mips

I use native libraries in my project. I have build them for ARM, ARMv7 and x86 architectures and just wonder if I should build them for MIPS too? Where can I find any statistical information about what part of Android devices run on MIPS processors. I want to understand if it has a meaning to make my APK larger in 4 - 5 MB because of the MIPS libs.

Comment: AFAIK MIPS phones are more popular in low-cost markets like the far east. I'm not aware of a MIPS based phone in the North America market. You would get better results asking in a different website. This type of question is not best suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will ask somewhere else.

Comment: @Andranik.  Is that ok now to leave the mips from our project. I too have a project sized 60MB

Comment: As I understand, it is ok for now. Because I have searched a lot and haven't found any information about devices with such processor architecture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APK file size: Maximum supported size is 50MB.

You should not have any problems.

As to device with MIPS I found only 2 official devices. Maybe it will be better to create this apk without this lib with other package name.

Comment: Please provide sources, or at least list the devices

Comment: Can you please list the device ?